# Recorrer una array en php

Tags: php, symfony

Trabajo con `php 7` y `symfony 4` tengo la necesidad de recorrer una array para poder navegar por sus propiedades y hacer un `if`
Vengo de `C#` cuando navego entre propiedades de un objeto hago lo siguiente `objeto.elemento`, en `php` se usa `objeto->elemento`?

Al array `distributivosx` debo eliminar el elemento que  cumple la condición, **no se si esta bien el código**?

El código que ocupo es el siguiente

```
$distributivos = [];
    
    foreach($distributivosx as $distributivo){
        if($distributivo->distributivocodmateria->materiatipo == "OFERTAINST"){
            $distributivos = array_pop($distributivosx);
        }else{
            $distributivos = $distributivosx;
        }
    }
```

**Es correcto?, que estoy haciendo mal?, porque $distributivos no me esta trayendo nada.**

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin Esa variable si me trae datos, a que te refieres con definida(declarada si) $distributivosx = $aulaDetalle->getDistributivos();

Comment: No termino de entender lo siguiente: _"debo quitarle el ultimo elemento si cumple la condición"_. Si es SOLO el último es el que necesitas controlar, ¿por que recorrer el arreglo entero?

Comment: @Marcos recorro el arreglo entero por que tiene que cumplirse la condición, si se cumple elimino el elemento que tiene ese estado, voy a editar mi pregunta